# {"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error\nORA-06512: at line 1"}

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have a file for logging stored procedure error to an Oracle database but at the time of executing the stored procedure I'm getting an error

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

Earlier I was using Microsoft enterprise logging but now I'm using `oracle.managed.dataaccess`. My code is shown below.

How to solve this portion false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default in my new code ?

Comment: It tells you that somewhere you send a value like `'abc'` to a numeric field. And Oracle can't implicitly convert it

Answer (score 4):

The first field to your stored procedure is defined as

```
abcd OUT INT
```

but you're binding this as

```
cmd = adapter.InputField(cmd, "abcd", logEntry.EventId, OracleDbType.Varchar2);
```

In other words, `abcd` is defined as `INT`, and it's an OUTPUT parameter, but you're binding it as if it's a character string INPUT parameter. I didn't go farther than that. Go back and check that all your bindings match the parameters.

Comment: you are right Bob it solved this problem . But now I'm facing some other issue like {"Input string was not in a correct format."} . My old code was db.AddParameter(storedProcCommand, "xyz", DbType.String, 32, ParameterDirection.Input, false, (byte)0, (byte)0, (string)null, DataRowVersion.Default, (object)logEntry.Severity.ToString()); now cmd = adapter.InputField(cmd, "severity", logEntry.Severity.ToString(), OracleDbType.Varchar2);cmd.Parameters["severity"].Size = 32;

Comment: I edited the question . Please look and suggest something to solve